# unable to load variable back from pickled file

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

```
import pickle
myDictOne = { "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3" }
myMovieTuple = (
"DDLJ",
"SRK",
"1993",
(
    (1, "Zara sa jhoom lu main"),
    (2, "Na jane mere "),
    (3, "Ghar a ja pardesi"),
    (4, "Mehdi laga ke rakhna")
)
)
myList = ["One", 3.5, 7, "two"]

with open('VariblesFile.pickle', 'wb') as myPickleFile:
    pickle.dump(myDictOne, myPickleFile)
    pickle.dump(myMovieTuple, myPickleFile)
    pickle.dump(myList,  myPickleFile)

with open('VariblesFile.pickle', 'rb') as myPickled_File:
    myNewDictOne = pickle.load(myPickled_File)
    myNewMovieTuple = pickle.load(myPickled_File)
    myNewList = pickle.load(myPickled_File)

print(myNewDictOne)
for i in myNewMovieTuple:
   for j in i:
        print(j)
print(myNewList)
```

I am getting below mentioned error message if i execute this program. Basically pickle file get created , but when i try to load back variables ,That is not working....Please help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
None
  File "E:/myNewPythonDir/CompletePythonDeveloperCourse/Module10/myOwnPickle.py", line 32, in <module>
    for i in myNewMovieTuple:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your code ran just fine on my machine (python 3.6.5 on Windows 10) What is your setup?

Comment: same here, what is your python version?

Comment: E:\myNewPythonDir>python --version
Python 3.6.4

Comment: I am also on windows10 ..probably need to upgrade my python to 3.6.5.

Comment: Anyways i am happy that there in no logical error in my code